# How to generate Excel xlsx files from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xlsx, openoffice.org

We are currently Exporting to Excel from `ui-grid` custom menus. The `xls` Excel file is generated from JavaScript (in the UI); however, we need to support the `xlsx` format. Problem is when we change the extension to `xlsx`, opening the file in Excel 2013is generates an error.

Here's a JavaScript code snippet show how we save the `xls` file:

```js
var blob = new Blob([html], { type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' });
saveAs(blob, "exported.xls");
```

Can we accomplish export to `xlsx` from `JavaScript`, without relying on some third party package?

I'm looking into `Open XML file formats` on `msdn` but it appears to be server-side oriented; that is, generating `xlsx` files from `c#`.

Here's an example generating from c# - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278309.aspx

I apologize if the question is too generic, as I'm struggling to find a proper solution.

regards

Comment: Why do you want to create xlsx files client-side? It's recommended to generate files server-side.

Comment: We do have that server-side feature as well in our application; however, our "quick export" option from ui-grid allows us to promptly export the ui-grid rows without an extra trip to the server. I'm seeing that it might not be possible to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript running where? If you mean in your browser then the short answer is no - the security model does not allow Javascript to create files.

But presumably the data is getting onto your page where javascript can read it from *somewhere* - so just generate the file there.

Comment: I just clarified my post that I'm referring to JavaScript in the browser. Problem is when we change the extension to `xlsx`, opening the file itself is generating an error.